# How can I add dismiss icon to phalcon session flash message with bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, phalcon, flash-message

My service configuration is as below;

```
$di->set('flashSession', function () {

 return new FlashSession([
        'error'   => 'alert alert-danger',
        'success' => 'alert alert-success',
        'notice'  => 'alert alert-info',
        'warning' => 'alert alert-warning'
    ]);
});
```

The bootstrap alert message work as appropriate but without the dismiss icon.

How can I make all my session alert message to have the dismiss icon.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick one for session flash message.

Create a file in the library directory with the name BootstrapFlash.php

Paste the code below

```
class BootstrapFlash extends \Phalcon\Flash\Session{

  public function __construct(){

    /* Pass html tags as receieved without reformating */

    parent::__construct();

    $this->setAutoescape(false);

  }

  public function message($type, $message){

    /* map the right class based on the message type */

    $types = array(
                      'success' => 'success',
                      'notice' => 'info',
                      'error' => 'danger',
                      'warning' => 'warning'
                    );

    $type = $types[$type];

    /* pretty title */

    $upper_type = strtoupper($type);

    /* Custom Alert Message with dismissible */

    $message = "<div class=\"alert alert-{$type} alert-dismissible\" role=\"alert\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-label=\"Close\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span></button><strong>{$upper_type}!</strong> {$message}</div>";

    parent::message($type, $message);
  }
}
```

In your service.php file in the config directory, set your flash session as below;

```
$di->set('flashSession', function () {

    /* Custom file available in the library Directory */

    return new BootstrapFlash();
});
```

With this, your flash session message will have dismiss close button.

You can as well modify the session alert message as desirable.